# How to pass the fields values of a form submitted through CF7 on wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, contact-form-7

I'm a WordPress enthusiast, I'm trying to accomplish something but I haven't found a way to.

Here's the deal, I have a form made with Contact Form 7 that I want to extract the values when the form is submitted and use them on the body of a WordPress page for a script I'm running when the form is submitted.

On my functions.php I have:

```
add_action('wpcf7_mail_sent','save_data_in_variables');
add_action('wpcf7_mail_failed','save_data_in_variables');

function save_data_in_variables($conference_form){
$submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
if (!$submission){
    echo 'Form was not sent';
}
$posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();
}

function wpc_vc_shortcode( $atts ) {
echo $posted_data['your-name'];
}
add_shortcode( 'name_in_the_form', 'wpc_vc_shortcode');
```

and on the body of the of the page I have a script running which submits data when the form is submitted but I want to replace the values with the values of the form using shortcode:

```
<script>
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
truestats.logEvent('Lead Conference', { id: '[name-in-the-form]' } );
}, false );
</script>
```

How do I accomplish this? So far no values are showing when I submit the form.

Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

You can get posted form data in your javascript, There is no need to create shortcode and pass it to javascript. Consider below example

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7submit', function( event ) {
        if(event.detail.contactFormId == 'CONTACT_FORM_ID'){   // condition for specific form ,replace "CONTACT_FORM_ID" 
                                                               // with form id you want to use this code for 
            var inputs = event.detail.inputs;
            for ( var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++ ) {
                if ( 'your-name' == inputs[i].name ) {
                    var name = inputs[i].value;
                    break;
                }
            }
            truestats.logEvent('Lead Conference', { id:  name } );
        }
    }, false );
</script>
```

**I had used 'wpcf7submit' event instead of 'wpcf7mailsent' event, you can use as per your need.**

You can check [DOM Events](https://contactform7.com/dom-events/) provided by contact form 7 for further reference.

Comment: how to get the dropdown value?